# Calculating relative frequencies of favorable outcome in experiment over course of many trials

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is some quick background about the problem:

```
There are two boxes with balls of different colors. Box 1 contains two blue 
balls, and one red ball. Box 2 contains two blue balls, three red balls, and 
one white ball.

The random experiment consists of generating a random number that follows a 
uniform distribution (min = 0, max = 1). If the number is greater than 0.5, 
then a sample with replacement of size 4 is drawn from box 1. If the random 
number is less than or equal to 0.5, then a sample without replacement of 
size 4 is drawn from box 2. The goal is to find the probabilities of getting 
either 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 blue balls.
```

I've created a matrix of a simulation of this experiment over 1000 trials that looks like this:

```
      [,1]   [,2]    [,3]   [,4]  
[1,] "red"  "blue"  "blue" "blue"
[2,] "blue" "blue"  "red"  "blue"
[3,] "blue" "blue"  "blue" "blue"
[4,] "red"  "white" "red"  "blue"
[5,] "blue" "blue"  "red"  "red" 
[6,] "red"  "blue"  "blue" "red"
```

And I have a 1000-element vector where the **i<sup>th</sup>**  element is the count of the number of occurrences of "blue" in the **i<sup>th</sup>**  row of the matrix.

And now my goal is to somehow put the relative frequencies of the number of blue balls into a `data frame` so I can then create a graph that looks like this:

[image]

But, I have no idea how to do this in R. I've experimented with some `for` loops but haven't gotten anywhere. Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's no way to identify the areas of R that you are having trouble with if you don't include code. You should create a "working example". Read [MVCE]. Looks like homework or self-study so throwing up your hands and saying "I have no clue" is not a great strategy in SO. (That graph was clearly created with ggplot2 code.)

Answer (score 0):

this isn't a complete or verified solution as I'm on mobile but the steps should be of use to you:

Concatenate matrix columns together and count the number of number of times "blue" occurs. Put this count in a data frame with its repetition and the value column which we'll use in a pivot:

```
library(stringr)

result_df <- data.frame(rep=1:nrow(your_data), 
blue_count=str_count(paste0(your_data[,1],your_data[,2],your_data[,3],your_data[,4]), "blue"), 
value=1)
```

Pivot the column "blue_count" so you have columns for each outcome and a 1 where indicates the outcome for that rep.

```
library(reshape)

pivot_df <- cast(result_df, rep ~ blue_count)
pivot_df[is.na(pivot_df)] <- 0
```

Cumulative sum the columns and divide by the rep to produce frequency for each outcome.

```
freq_df <- data.frame(rep=pivot_df[,1], 
outcome_0=cumsum(pivot_df[,2])/pivot_df[,1],
outcome_1=cumsum(pivot_df[,3])/pivot_df[,1],
outcome_2=cumsum(pivot_df[,4])/pivot_df[,1],
outcome_3=cumsum(pivot_df[,5])/pivot_df[,1],
outcome_4=cumsum(pivot_df[,6])/pivot_df[,1])
```

Plot using ggplot2, you may need to unpivot the data.frame.